# canOpenUrl fail "org-appextension-feature-password-management" (PayPal)

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, ios9, openurl

PayPal payment not working as I get failure on opening a URL

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "org-appextension-feature-password-management://" - error: "(null)"
```

In accordance with the documentation I added org-appextension-feature-password-management to my info.plist, but I still get the below error.

**Ideas what I might have overlooked?**

[image: Error screenshot & Info.plist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in PayPal SDK.

**The error only occurs in the *PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork* setting**. When you switch over to ***PayPalEnvironmentSandbox*** or ***PayPalEnvironmentProduction*** the error does not persist (assuming you have set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes correctly).